# event for data attribute instead of class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create the event based on data attribute instead of class name

```
<button type="button"
      class="btn btn-danger approvalbtn" data-approvestatus="N" data-dismiss="modal">Reject</button>
Now I have added attribute as `$('.approvalbtn').prop("disabled",true);`
```

I want to check with `data-approvestatus="N"` in jquery

Comment: did you try $('button[data-approvestatus=N]')  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
$('button[data-approvestatus=N]').click(function(){
 alert("Clicked");
 //$(this).prop("disabled",true) you can disable it too
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button type="button"
      class="btn btn-danger approvalbtn" data-approvestatus="N" data-dismiss="modal">Reject</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the attribute selector! This is how:

```
$("[data-approvestatus='N']").prop("disabled", true);
```

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/